# Error with if statement to include pages in php

Tags: php

I have a group of pages, and I want to include one of them dependent on a variable in url, but the page is always appear is dashboard

```
link1 : index.php?pth=&page=dashboard
link2 : index.php?pth=modules/institution&page=inst_classification
```

if statement :

```
if (isset($page) && !empty($page)) {
                    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);    
                    $pth = htmlspecialchars($_GET["pth"]);    
                }else{  
                    $page ='dashboard';
                    $pth = ''; 
                }
                include ('../admin/template/'.$template_fldr.'/html/'.$pth.$page.'.php');
```

thanks!

Comment: What is the error? - Also, no need to use `isset()` and `!empty()` in the same clause, it's enough to just use `!empty()`

Comment: the error is always dashboard page appear in the  two links

Comment: print the value of `$page`, error is there.

Comment: Also, might wanna consider the order of your code, you are checking if `$page` is there, yet (from what we can see) the first time you declare `$page` is INSIDE the same if clause.. Do turn on error reporting.

Comment: Undefined variable: page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access `$page` before you write to it. You also never check for the existance of your `pth` value. Try:

```
if (empty($_GET['page']) || empty($_GET['pth'])) {
    $page ='dashboard';
    $pth = '';  
}else{  
    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);    
    $pth = htmlspecialchars($_GET["pth"]);    
}
include ('../admin/template/'.$template_fldr.'/html/'.$pth.$page.'.php');
```

You probably also need a `/` here in your include, if `modules/institution/inst_classification.php` is the file you are looking for:

`include('../admin/template/'.$template_fldr.'/html/'.$pth.'/'.$page.'.php');` - but that is not clear from your question.

Comment: thanks , this error appear : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.php'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: I were missing a `.` between `$page` and `'.php'`. I fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET["page"]) && isset($_GET["pth"])) {
                    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]); 
                    $pth = htmlspecialchars($_GET["pth"]);
                } else {
                    $page = 'dashboard';
                    $pth = '';
                }
                include ('../admin/template/'.$template_fldr.'/html/'.$pth.'/'.$page.'.php');
```